# Reading the text from a textbox in another application

Tags: vb6

I try to read text from another app(for example Notepad or Wordpad).
I must do that in VB 6 in witch I not have programmed before, but i cannot use other language.

I find code for Vb.Net and i modified it for VB 6, but i always get error: "Run-time Error '424': Object Required"

Code is:

```
     Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = &HE
     Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String _
) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
    ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
    ByVal hWndChildAfter As Long, _
    ByVal lpszClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpszWindowName As String _
) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "USER32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, _
    wParam As Any, lParam As Any) As Long





Private Sub Command1_Click()
         Dim notepadHandle As Long
         notepadHandle = FindWindow("Notepad", vbNullString)
         Dim childhandle As Long
         childhandle = FindWindowEx(notepadHandle, 0, "Edit", vbNullString)
         If notepadHandle = 0 Then
             MessageBox.Show ("can't find")
         Else
             'MessageBox.Show (CStr(childhandle))
          '   MessageBox.Show (WindowText(childhandle))
              MessageBox.Show (WindowText(childhandle))
End If

     End Sub

     Public Function WindowText(ByVal window_hwnd As Long) As String
         Dim txtlen As Integer
         WindowText = ""
         If window_hwnd = 0 Then Exit Function
         txtlen = SendMessage(window_hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, _
             0)
         If txtlen = 0 Then Exit Function
         txtlen = txtlen + 1
         Dim txt As String
         txt = String(txtlen + 1, Chr$(0))
         txt = Convert.ToString(SendMessage(window_hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, txtlen, txt))

         WindowText = Convert.ToString(txt)

     End Function
```

Where I make mistake?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't expect VB.NET samples to work in VB6. The two languages are incompatible on a number of levels, not just because VB6 doesn't use the .NET framework. The syntax is slightly different, too.

First of all stylistically, declarations in VB are generally at the top of the procedure. This is because VB scoping rules are done per procedure, and ignores all blocks in the code.

VB6 doesn't really have static objects, per se, although you can fake it with "global" objects, which automatically instantiate a public (i.e. from an external component) multi-use class the first time you try to bind to it.

The VB6 message box command is simply **MsgBox()**. **Convert.ToString** is simply **CStr()**, although VB tends to automatically convert to string when it is required without you having to do any work.

In any case, the line::

```
txt = Convert.ToString(SendMessage(window_hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, txtlen, txt))
```

... is wrong on more than the conversion. The SendMessage() API call returns a Long value, not a string. In this case `txt` is the string buffer.

In my version, I have greatly simplified this by using the Unicode version of SendMessage(). This means that I can simply preload the return value `WindowText` with null chars, and use this directly with the API call. **StrPtr()** returns a pointer to the Unicode buffer relating to the VB string. The API understands this, and uses this buffer with no problem. I just have to add one to the length when calling SendMessage() so that it takes into account that VB6 strings are automatically null-terminated.

```
Private Const WM_GETTEXT                    As Long = &HD
Private Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH              As Long = &HE

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String _
) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
    ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
    ByVal hWndChildAfter As Long, _
    ByVal lpszClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpszWindowName As String _
) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "USER32" Alias "SendMessageW" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByRef wParam As Any, ByRef lParam As Any _
) As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim notepadHandle           As Long
    Dim childhandle             As Long

    notepadHandle = FindWindow("Notepad", vbNullString)
    childhandle = FindWindowEx(notepadHandle, 0, "Edit", vbNullString)

    If notepadHandle = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show "can't find"
    Else
        MsgBox WindowText(childhandle)
    End If

End Sub

Public Function WindowText(ByVal window_hwnd As Long) As String

    Dim txtlen              As Long

    If window_hwnd = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    txtlen = SendMessage(window_hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, ByVal 0, ByVal 0)
    If txtlen = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    WindowText = String$(txtlen, vbNullChar)
    SendMessage window_hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, ByVal (txtlen + 1), ByVal StrPtr(WindowText)

End Function
```

Comment: My vb6 has static variables. And Static procedures. Static Statement
      

Used at procedure level to declare variables and allocate storage space. Variables declared with the Static statement retain their values as long as the code is running.

Comment: @phd443322 I was really thinking about classes defined as "static", not variables.

Comment: The properties/methods can be static in a class. Property Set Statement
      

Declares the name, arguments, and code that form the body of a Property procedure, which sets a reference to an object.

Syntax

[Public | Private | Friend] [Static] Property Set name ([arglist,] reference)
[statements]
[Exit Property] 
[statements]

End Property

Comment: @phd443322 Sadly, whilst it is true you can add Static to the declaration of a method or property in a class, this keyword does not make the method or property static in the sense of the way it is used in `.NET`. What it does is to implicitly modify the *variables* declared with **Dim** inside that method or property to be **Static**.

Answer (score 2):

Thereis no object in your code. However msgbox is just msgbox not msgbox.show. This tricks VB into thinking it's an object rather than a function (being used as a sub).

Also as it's a sub there are no brackets. Only things that return values require brackets. Of all the basics only vb.net has brackets for subs.